# Can I use a .Include on a IList?

Tags: c#, angularjs, typescript

I'm trying to move everything from depository into a service for the first time, and I'm having a few errors that I'm hoping are just syntax issues.  It doesn't look like I'm able to use .Include to get a user back when I pull my list of questions.  Does this look like something I should be able to do?  Is there a better way?

```
 public IList<Question> SearchQuestions() {
            return _repo.Query<Question>().Include(q => q.User).ToList();
```

Comment: To see which methods are available on the IList interface, you could check the MSDN documentation. If you do this, you'll notice that Include does not appear in that list. Unless you cast your interface to an implementation of IList that does contain the Include method, then you'll be able to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few issues there:

- The return type should be after the function parentheses
- You can do it all in one arrow function.
- No need for `public` (It's the default)
- No need for the 2nd cast, it'll be done by the return type

BUT, overall I don't see any thing else that is not possible in TypeScript.

```
SearchQuestions = (): IList<Question> => _repo.Query().Include(q => q.User).ToList();
```

Comment: The return type should be after the function parenthesis?

Comment: yeap, you wrote `public IList<Question searchQuestions() {...` but you should have written `public searchQuestions():IList<Question> {...`